# Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined - Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Console:

```
my.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (my.js:8)
at Object../app/javascript/packs/my.js (my.js:136)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:22)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at bootstrap:83
at bootstrap:83
```

Посмотрел в скомпанованном application.js, и my.js стоит выше typeahead.bundle.js( библиотека содержащая в себе Bloodhound).
Дайте совет как организовать порядок подгрузки js библиотек правильно.

[Репозиторий](https://github.com/gemcave/rails_shop)

Comment: А если my.js поставить самой последней строкой в application.js?

Comment: не, в новой rails по алфавитному порядку все компонуется в один файл.